# How to setup remote server name for Openvpn in pfsense

Tags: openvpn, pfsense

My company runs `pfsense 2.3.2-RELEASE` as vpn server. All generated Openvpn config file are like this:

```
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
tls-client
client
remote 192.168.100.2 1194 udp
setenv opt block-outside-dns
lport 0
verify-x509-name "******" name
auth-user-pass
ns-cert-type server
```

The remote server is an internal ip. Hence I have to manually change it to the vpn gateway domain name before I pass the config file to the user.
How can I use the vpn gateway domain name?

---

I found the setting for remote server host name. It is in `OpenVPN` - `Client Export Utility`, `Client Connection Behavior` section. I changed `Host Name Resolution` to `Other` and manually specified the host name.

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear what you are asking, but "remote" can take either an IP address or a domain name - so it quite valid to replace "remote 192.168.100.2 1194 udp" with "remote domain.example.com 1194 udp".

If your difficulties relate to a different internal and external IP address and how to have the same name for both depending on where the request is coming from, that problem is solved using split DNS.  Its not possible to provide specific advice without knowing a lot more about your network setup and how you are currently using DNS, however there are a number of common solutions:

1. Use DNSMasq on your LAN and put a mapping from your desired domain to a  local IP address in your hosts file.  Ensure that all computers on your LAN are using the DNSMasq nameserver and that DNSMasq is translating hosts into IP addresses.
2. If you are using BIND for authorative DNS, Use Split DNS - this setup will allow different zones depending on where the request is originating from.  If you are using BIND for recursive DNS, set up a zone for your domain in your local BIND and add the appropriate local domain - IP mapping.

Depending on the complexity of your network - if you can put the OpenVPN server on a seperate subnet such that all requests - both internal and external - go through the firewall, you may be able to add a line to the firewall to intercept requests from your LAN going to ext.ip port 1194 and redirect them to your OpenVPN box, while also port-forwarding/pinholing this from your WAN Interface.

Comment: I took a second look at pfsense, and I found the setting for remote server host name. It is in `OpenVPN` - `Client Export Utility`, `Client Connection Behavior` section. I changed `Host Name Resolution` to `Other` and manually specified the host name.
Thank you for your information :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the setting for remote server host name. It is in `OpenVPN` - `Client Export Utility`, `Client Connection Behavior` section. I changed `Host Name Resolution` to `Other` and manually specified the host name.